# SQLite DataBase for Windows Phone 8 that can support any CPU

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm using Sqlite Database version 3.7.15 for Windows Phone 8, but the problem is it only supports x86 CPU configuration. Is there some other option that can support any CPU Configuration for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you mean [Sqlite-net-wp8](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8), then this contains a native component that is either built for the x86 or ARM platform.

You must use an ARM build for running on a device, and an x86 build for running on the emulator. You cannot use AnyCPU build due to the native code.